define multiple methods for comparison at once using the same principle
I am building a binary tree in python defining the node as a class. I wanted the node to have a value and be comparable to other nodes in order to, for example, sort a list of them.
I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way to avoid explicitly defining all comparison methods (__le__, __lt__, __eq__). I tried this and it works:
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, name=None, left=None, right=None):
    self.value=value
    self.name = name
    self.right, self.left = right, left
  
  def is_leaf(self):
    return self.right is None and self.left is None
  
  def __le__(self, other):
    return self.value.__le__(other.value) # or (self.value <= other.value)
  # same for __lt__, __eq__

But I wanted to reuse the code. More generally, I want the object to reference self.value for a list of dunder methods, without explicitly coding each one.
I considered forcing inheritence from same base class, e.g. if values are numbers: class Node(float), or, in the init:
   def __init__(self, value, name=None, left=None, right=None):
     type(value).__init__(value)
     # etc.

But they seem to me as a bad practice since they add a lot of potentially unexpected behaviours.
Is there a pythonic / elegant way to avoid explicitly defining all comparison methods in the class when the all obey a common standard?

You could probably automate the definitions of the methods with a loop like for op in [operators.__le__, operators.__eq__, ...]:

There might also be something you can do with decorators.

It might be better to not define an ordering of Nodes at all, but rather specify a key function when you actually sort. sorted(list_of_nodes, key=lambda n: n.value).

IIUC, you can use functools.total_ordering:
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, name=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.right, self.left = right, left

    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.right is None and self.left is None

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.value < other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other


n1 = Node(10)
n2 = Node(10)
n3 = Node(20)

print(f"{n1 < n2 = }")
print(f"{n1 > n2 = }")
print(f"{n1 == n2 = }")
print(f"{n1 < n3 = }")
print(f"{n1 > n3 = }")
print(f"{n1 > 5 = }")

Prints:
n1 < n2 = False
n1 > n2 = False
n1 == n2 = True
n1 < n3 = True
n1 > n3 = False
n1 > 5 = True

